# Change an ID upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know how to change a class name with another class upon click, but not sure how to do so when using id instead.

Below is how the class is setup:

```
<script>

    $(function(){
      $(".collapseArrow").click(function(){
        $(".collapseArrow").removeClass("collapseArrow")
        $(this).addClass("collapseArrowUp")
        return false;
      })
    })
    </script>
```

The reason for that is that the class is already being used and i have to use the id to style it instead.

Comment: Wouldn't it be difficult to maintain id on next click?

Comment: you want click event id or change only id when click on ".collapseArrow"?

Comment: can you share the html sample.. and what do you mean by class is already used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Plain Javascript approach:-**

This approach takes advantage of the `this` keyword as follows...

HTML:

```
<div id="oldId" onclick="changeId(this)"></div>
```

JS:

```
function changeId(element) {
    element.id = "someNewId";
}
```

or simply (in one line) as part of the HTML

```
<div id="oldId" onclick="this.id='someNewId';"></div>
```

---

**jQuery approach:-**

Use the `attr()` function as follows...

```
$(function(){
     $("#oldId").click(function(){
       $("#oldId").attr("id","newId");
        return false;
     });
});
```

---

EDIT: As requested, I will give a piece of code to toggle between 2 ids.

HTML:

```
<div id="firstId" onclick="toggleId(this)"></div>
```

JS:

```
function toggleId(element) {
    if(element.id == "firstId") {
        element.id = "secondId";
    } else { //This will only execute when element.id == "secondId"
        element.id = "firstId";
    }
}
```

Comment: this could be shorter, using onclick="this.id='bla';" ?

Comment: Understandable, just thought to add this as well. I rarely see the use for assigning a new id within the click event as you would end up with a large event vs sending it to a function. +1 regardless

Comment: I will add the short approach too. Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: thank you the js approach seems to have work best function changeId(element) {
    element.id = "someNewId";
} one minor request could this be a loop where everytime it clicks it switches between these two id such as lets say there two id someNewId1 and someNewId2 now you click on it it goes to someNewId2 and if you click again I want it to go to someNewId1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `attr()` function

```
<script>
  $(function(){
     $("#collapseArrow").click(function(){
       $("#collapseArrow").attr('id',"collapseArrowUp");
        return false;
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 $(this).attr("id"',"new id");
```

But i would use classes and add important to override existing css rules

Hope i helped

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the id, do it with multiple classes.
This could help you...

```
$(function(){
  $(".collapseArrow").click(function(){
    $(".collapseArrow").removeClass("up")
    $(this).addClass("up")
    return false;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

*i have to use the id to style it instead.*

I suggest you not to do this because in the dom structure `id`s have most preference against the class names. So this would be little difficult to override the styles which have been applied with the ids.

Instead i would recommend to use classes instead:

```
$(function() {
  $(".collapseArrow").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("collapseArrow collapseArrowUp")
    return false;
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".collapseArrow").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("collapseArrow collapseArrowUp")
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.collapseArrow::before {
  content: "[-]"
}
.collapseArrowUp::before{
  content: "[+]"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class='collapseArrow'></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not change an id. If you need to use a different selector to select the same element, add another class to the element, e.g.

```
<span class="collapsArrow SomethingMeaningful"></span>
```

Then you just need to use a different selector method:

```
$( "span[class~='SomethingMeaningful']" )
    .removeClass("collapseArrow")
    .addClass("collapseArrowUp");
```

Then you can style the element with:

```
.SomethingMeaningful{

}
```